# How can I change the "Application" class in execution time?

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

We had an idea of let the user choose their own backgroud image (between a set of predefined images) of our GeneXus generated app.

Is it possible to change the ["Application" class](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?30887,Application%20Class%20for%20Smart%20Devices,) programatically? It would be cool because we could change the "Application Colors" as well.

Our second option is to create a couple of Table classes with the backgrounds and change in the start event.

But it would be perfect if we could use different "Application" classes.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to change the Application class in runtime. The best option is the one you describe: use a Table and change the Table's class.